# Distinct counts based on dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to create a new table based on the following table:

```
SubjectNumber    TestDates    
001              11/12/12
001              01/10/15
001              04/03/13
002              05/21/14
003              08/06/15
002              09/12/18
002              03/30/12
003              09/07/18
004              10/14/11
005              02/05/14
005              02/06/14
```

I need a new table that will include the following:

1) Subject number

2) Their first test date

3) Their last test date

4) A count of the total number of tests

5) A column with 0's and 1's indicating whether or not the subject had any two test dates that were at least 30 days apart

The new table should look like the following:

```
SubjectNumber    FirstTestDate     LastTestDate     TestCount    ThirtyDaysApart
001              11/12/12          01/10/15         3            1
002              03/30/12          09/12/18         3            1
003              08/06/15          09/07/18         2            1
004              10/14/11                           1            0
005              02/05/14          02/06/14         2            0
```

I'm using SQL Server 2017.

I have a temporary table called #Temp1 that I'd like to store the data in. This table is called #Temp.

```
Insert into #Temp1
SELECT SubjectNumber, WHERE 
CASE MIN(TestDates) then FirstTestDate = TestDates
END
CASE MAX(TestDates) then LastTestDate = TestDates
END
FROM #Temp;
```

Comment: Thanks for your requirements. Any code from ur side..

Comment: Are you trying to create a new table with the results in the table, or just a query that returns those results?  What have you tried that is not working?  We can help you with specific issues, but this is not a code writing service.  You need to show that you have made an effort to solve your problem.

Comment: I'd like to create a new table. Sorry, code incoming.

Comment: That seems lovely. What's stopping you? (In other words, please read [ask], especially the part where it says we need to see your efforts). Also,please note that sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: @ZoharPeled Code has been updated. I'm looking for a way to add the counts as a column and to determine if a subject has any two dates 30 days apart.

Comment: _Any two dates_ is ambiguous. What if we have Jan 1, Jan 15 and Feb 10. Does it count?

Comment: Am I correct in interpreting your expected results that, if a given `SubjectNumber` only has 1 record (as is the case with `004`), you don't want to show anything for the max date? Because technically, for `004`, `10/14/11` is both the min and max value.

Comment: Yes you're right. I guess it could be shown as both, because it is in fact both the max and the min date.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `lag()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select subjectnumber, min(testdate), max(testdate),
       max(case when prev_testdate < dateadd(day, -30, testdate) then 1 else 0 end) as diff30
from (select t.*,
             lag(testdate) over (partition by subjectnumber order by testdate) as prev_testdate
      from t
     ) t
group by subjectnumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

The only tricky part is checking if two dates within a group are 30 days apart. Note that the following query returns 1 if ***any*** two dates, not necessarily consecutive, are 30 days apart:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT SubjectNumber, MIN(TestDates) FirstTestDate, MAX(TestDates) LastTestDate, COUNT(TestDates) TestCount
    FROM @yourdata
    GROUP BY SubjectNumber
)
SELECT *
FROM cte AS t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS ThirtyDaysApart
    FROM @yourdata AS o
    INNER JOIN @yourdata AS n ON o.SubjectNumber = n.SubjectNumber AND n.TestDates >= DATEADD(DAY, 30, o.TestDates)
    WHERE o.SubjectNumber = t.SubjectNumber
) AS CA
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3bd1be07b8745e8c9c4c04ac2a3693c7)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using lag() function

```
select subjectnumber,min(TestDates),max(TestDates),count(TestDates),
case when count(case when pdatediff=30 then 1 end)>=2 then 1 else 0 end as ThirtyDaysApart
from
(
select subjectnumber,TestDates,COALESCE (DATEDIFF(DAY, 
       LAG(TestDates) OVER (PARTITION BY subjectnumber
            ORDER BY TestDates), TestDates) ,0) as pdatediff
from tablenmae
)X group by subjectnumber
```